# Looking for a different SQL provider / connection string

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, database-connection, connection-string

I want to connect to a Microsoft Access 2007 Database file (.accdb). I use the following provider to connect to the database and it works fine:

```
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MyDatabase.accdb";
        con.Open();
```

Provided I have Microsoft Office OR the Access Database Engine installed. My question is: is it possible to connect to a .accdb file without having either of those components installed? and if so, what would the connection string look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... Provided I have Microsoft Office OR the Access Database Engine installed. My question is: is it possible to connect to a .accdb file without having either of those components installed?

No. The older 32-bit "Jet" database engine is part of a basic Windows install, but

- it can only work with .mdb files, and
- it is only available to 32-bit applications.

If you need to manipulate an .accdb file then you need the newer [Access Database Engine](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255) (a.k.a. "ACE").